# Setting up React.js with Django failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, frontend

I am currently learning React.js and I followed some tutorials on Youtube for React.js basics.

I didn't initially use `npm run build`(used it after I'm done coding the frontend) and I created my react frontend app inside my Django project.

When I am running `npm start` on cmd, react app works perfectly fine on localhost:3000.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3BwC.png)

But after I tried to run `npm run build` and done setting up, `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `template_dirs`, `STATIC_URL` and such, when I runserver on port:8000 which is default for django, all I can see is a white screen, I included console on the screenshot for error references:

[empty django page with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM8ex.png)

I even tried to put some text inside the body 'frontend/build/index.html' just to see if Django can access the template dirs, and the text put in shown on Django homepage localhost:8000.

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: If react-icons and bootstrap-icons is an example of webpack, I installed it both on my react frontend app.

Comment: @Oussama If react-icons and bootstrap-icons is an example of webpack, I installed it both on my react frontend app.

Comment: hmmmm no i meant django-webpack-loader... but never mind... Can you please share: 1) All lines related to static files in your settings.py 2) the static folder structure 3) the expected location of the react .js files in the static folder 4) the full path to the missing files chrome is trying to load